# jQuery.ajax, cache and timestamps

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, caching

I'm using the jquery.ajax methods in order to send GET-requests to the server, caching should be busted, so cache is set to false, so far so good.

jQuery automatically adds a timestamp (I guess epoch-milliseconds) to the request-url in order to bust caching. Is there a way to control the timestamp used by jQuery? (Even seconds would be sufficient and help the server to do it's caching properly,…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing the code of jQuery manually, not cleanly.

Diving into the jQuery code, we see that the nonce (which is just the timestamp in this case) generated by jQuery is pretty hard-coded in there.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/91850ecbbe04ad8f5d89dc050aa1d9002047c435/src/ajax.js (Line 607)

The `nonce` variable there is passed in, but if we follow the trail back it leads to `jQuery.now()`, which is just an alias for `(new Date).getTime()`.

So your options are:

1) Append your own value on to each URI manually, and just ignore jQuery's value.

2) **Dirty**. Override jQuery's `now()` function to return the value you seek. Gives me shivers just thinking about it! You may have other unexpected errors as a result of this, so I wouldn't recommend it, but it is possible. If you're still returning a timestamp that is close to the current one, maybe it wouldn't be too bad, but that may not be your case at all. A naive example: https://jsfiddle.net/pf5pskg5/

Comment: thx for the quick reply, so I will have to do it manually (not the dirty version ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache: false});
```

What this does is tell the browser to never cache AJAX requests.

I've experienced strange behavior because of certain browsers tendency to cache AJAX requests, especially when they're HTTP GET requests.

IE 11 will attempt to use its cached version of AJAX requests AND LIE ABOUT THE HTTP STATUS returned by the server ("304 Not Modified") if you don't turn off AJAX request caching.

Comment: this just helps me to set the cache-param false for all future requests. I want to influence what timestamp is being used when cache = false;

Comment: @nabittened Why are you trying to do that? What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: if the timestamps are seonds, it helps the server to still cache concurrent user-requests. e.g.

http://server.com/request?_12345    (imagine some milliseconds example)
and
http://server.com/request?_12346 

cannot be cached by the server, event if the content has not changed in this time-period

whereas

http://server.com/request?_12 and
http://server.com/request?_12

could still be cached and http://server.com/request?_13 would be a new one (from another or the same user)

Comment: @nabittened [**What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I will still be able to bundle requests by concurrent users

Comment: @nabittened Why is it important that your AJAX requests be cached?